# How to avoid double spend with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I think that's some noob question
But. Say my user has balance. I do

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT `balance` FROM `us` WHERE login=?");
if($balance>20){
 $sql = "UPDATE `us` SET `balance` = `balance`-20 WHERE login = :login";
}
```

So, that's fine if I have just request. But if in the same time 2 users gonna do 2 requests balance will be -20. That's not good for me. Any samples of save transactions to avoid double spends?

Comment: I *was* going to say "Even W3Fools knows about transactions!", but of *coooourse* they don't...

Comment: [Transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

Comment: `UPDATE ... WHERE balance > 20`…

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start a transaction, *lock* the records you are going to update, perform the update, then commit the transaction.

In SQL:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT `balance` FROM `us` WHERE login=:login FOR UPDATE
UPDATE `us` SET `balance` = `balance`-20 WHERE login = :login
COMMIT
```

Note the "FOR UPDATE" in the second statement; this is *very important* and locks the selected records for subsequent update.

Also note that some versions of MySQL need the table to be of a specific type in order to actually support transactions.

Comment: This is actually really neat. I never knew about Transactions in MySQL before. Thanks!